# NotificationListenerService Ошибки при работе приложения

Tags: java, android

Скопировал данный [проект](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/11/reading-notification-using-notificationlistenerservice.html) .
Компилируется без ошибок. Но при вызове уведомлений, на экране ничего не отображается. В логи приходит такое сообщение:

```
11 - 02 15: 44: 39.347 20555 - 20576 / timer.notificationtwo W / NotificationListenerService[NotificationService]: Error running onNotificationPosted
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()'
on a null object reference
at timer.notificationtwo.NotificationService.onNotificationPosted(NotificationService.java: 30)
at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted(NotificationListenerService.java: 160)
at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService$INotificationListenerWrapper.onNotificationPosted(NotificationListenerService.java: 627)
at android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub.onTransact(INotificationListener.java: 71)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java: 455)
```

Может кто-то подсказать, по какой причине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что при вызове `String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();` в строке №30 в файле `NotificationService.java` свойство `tickerText == null`.

Стоит добавить проверку на null. Например так:

```
String ticker = "";
try {
    ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Блестяще :) из серии совет саперу: *если при шаге вперед вам оторвало ногу, значит вы наступили на мину*, а нельзя как то проверить `tickerText==null` без генерации Exception?

Comment: @Barmaley Ключевое слово например.

Comment: Совершенно верно, *например, если вам оторвало ногу* - далее по тексту :)

Comment: @Barmaley Не совсем. Здесь больше из серии: _Если вы не поставили табличку, что здесь есть мины - будьте готовы ко всему_. А вот если бы поставили, то ide сама предупредила бы.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ticker ="";

if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null)
{
     ticker = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString();
}
else
{
     ticker = "Пусто";
}
```